# Сохранить данные парса в CSV файл

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Товарищи, доброго времени суток.

Помогите, пожалуйста, сохранить результат парса в файл csv.

Имеется функция:

```
def parse_page(self, text):
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(text, "lxml")
    container_port = soup.find("table", class_="port")
    tr_list = container_port.find_all("tr")
    for tr in tr_list:
        td_list = tr.find_all("td")
        for td in td_list:
            line = (str(td.text)).strip()
            print(line, end=";")
        print("\n")
```

Результат принта:

```
0;tcp;trojan;REx;Trojans;
0;tcp,udp;;Reserved;IANA;
1;udp;tcpmux;TCP Port Service Multiplexer (IANA registered)
```

Нужно всё это сохранить в CSV с разделителем `;`

Я в этом деле новичок, прошу помощи, большое спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Входного xml/html, к сожалению, не представили. Делал на глаз.

Особо ничего не меняем. В цикле по tr_list все ячейки td из строки tr объединяем в одну строку с разделителем ';' через join(). После, если нужно, печатаем, а после выводим в файл.

```
def parse_page(self, text, filename='out.csv', delimiter=';'):
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(text, "lxml")
    container_port = soup.find("table", class_="port")
    with open(filename, 'w') as file:
        tr_list = container_port.find_all("tr")
        for tr in tr_list:
            line = delimiter.join([(str(td.text)).strip() for td in tr.find_all("td")])
            if line:  # Проверка пустой строки
                print(line)
                file.write('{}\n'.format(line))
```

Comment: Отлично, спасибо. подошло. 
А можно ещё, как можно из этого вывода удалить пустые строки.
Я пробовал `line.find("br").extract()` но что-то не получается.
Спасибо.

Comment: Можно попробовать `print(line); file.write('{}\n'.format(line))` под `if line:` завести.

Comment: Можно поподробней, пожалуйста.

Comment: Поправил код в ответе. Третья строка снизу

Comment: Спасибо большое!-

Answer (score 1):

Если не мудрствовать лукаво, то надо использовать *pandas*.

```
import pandas as pd

# Введённую строку преобразуем в DataFrame
df ​ =​ pd.DataFrame(StringIO(csv_data))

# DataFrame сохраняем в виде CVS файла
 df.to_csv(​ "tmp.csv"​)
```

Работа с pandas подробно описана в отличной книжке

Абдрахманов М.И. Pandas. Работа с данными. - devpractice.ru. 2018. - 141 с.: ил.
На странице 53 ответ на Ваш вопрос.